# How do I answer same password prompt multiple times when using unrar on a multi-file archive?

Tags: freebsd, rar

In particular when unrar has to rebuild the missing parts with rev files.

I have a "multiple files rar-archive" that is password protected. A couple .rar files that compose the archive are missing but I have enough .rev files to do the recovery.

I use the following command to extract the files from the archive:

```
unrar x -pPassword file-part01.rar
```

The problem is that unrar will ask for the password again for each rar archive when starting the rebuild of the missing parts.

I am using FreeBSD 9.

Update:
-list of files I have:

```
part01.rar
part02.rar
part03.rar
part04.rar
part06.rar
part01.rev
```

Notice the missing part05.rar file.
If I do:

```
unrar x -pPassword par01.rar
```

it start working and when unrar finds I am missing part 5 will start reconstructing it with the .rev file. My problem is that it will then ask for the Password again for each one of the part files (i this example it asks 6 times the same password).

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things:

```
unrar x -pPassword *.rar
```

Or

```
for i in *.rar; do unrar -pPassword $i; done
```

In case of incremental rar files (r00, r01, etc), you can change rar to r*: `unrar x *.r*`

Comment: This commands would be fine for multiple rar archives, but I have only one archive made of multiple rar files (i.e. they are all needed for the extraction to work). The problem is that once it start unraring one of the files it will ask for the password multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use`[expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) (manpage [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)) to supply the password whenever the password prompt is asked

I believe something like

```
spawn unrar x -pPassword file-part01.rar 
expect "password:"
send "My_Password"
```

Should work with a little tweaking

Comment: I tried it this way but I was not able to get it to work. It works for the first time it asks a password but not for all the remain times. I thought it timed out but setting the timeout to a long time didn't work either.

Comment: You might need to run the "expect" "send" parts of it more than once. Hence my mention of tweaking

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work but not always and I don't understand why. I will have to experiment a bit more.